# Images not appearing on buttons when user control is in referenced assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a main WPF application which references a WPF User Control Library that I created. In the library, I have one user control and an images folder (images used by user control). Here is part of the XAML that I have in the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Alstom.UserControls.MainToolbar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Alstom.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="3440">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="Subway" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Subway.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="Globe" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Globe.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="Gavel" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Gavel.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="Clipboard" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Clipboard.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="EllipsisVertical" Source="/images/MainToolbar/EllipsisVertical.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="Check" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Check.png"/>
    <Image x:Key="Bell" Source="/images/MainToolbar/Bell.png"/>
```

The user control has buttons which I wrote like the following (note that I defined the Content property as StaticResource:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{StaticResource Subway}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Height="48"/>
```

When I double click the user control, in the designer, I see the images on the buttons.

But I created a main WPF application in my solution which references the external assembly like so:

```
<Window x:Class="MainToolBar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:myMainToolbar="clr-namespace:Alstom.UserControls;assembly=Alstom.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="auto" Width="3440" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<Grid>
    <myMainToolbar:MainToolbar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

When I double-click the MainWindow.xaml, I don't see the images on the button in the designer, nor when I run it.

What do I need to do to show the images at runtime? In the user control project, the images have a Build Action = Resource. But I tried to change one of them to Embedded Resource, and it still did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the build action of the images to **Resource** and use a pack URI:

```
<Image x:Key="Subway" Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/images/MainToolbar/Subway.png"/>
```

Don't forget to change "YourAssemblyName" to the actual name of your assembly/WPF User Control Library project.

**Pack URIs in WPF:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx